# symfony2 form twig input value

Tags: forms, symfony, input, twig

I am doing a form with symfony2 and twig, form who get infos from BDD.
I want to customize render in function of some informations.

If my data chanson is empty, I want to show input to set it.
If my data is not empty I want to show a paragraphe who shows data, and a link for modify the value and show the input.

I try something like that :

```
{% if form_widget(session.chanson).attrvalue!='' %}
 <p>{{form_widget(session.chanson).attrvalue}} <a>modify</a></p>
{% else %}
 <p>{{ form_label(session.chanson,"Chanson : ") }}
 {{ form_errors(session.chanson) }}
 {{ form_widget(session.chanson) }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

It's not working. I try with value instead of attrvalue, it's not working neither.
Here is what symfony say : `Item "attrvalue" for "<input type="text" id="form_chanson" name="form[chanson]" required="required" value="La Rage" />" does not exist in CDUserBundle:Prof:edit_session.html.twig at line 19`

Did someone know the issue ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `app.session.chanson` variable is empty instead using:

```
{% if app.session.chanson %}
   <p>{{ app.session.chanson }} <a href="#">modify</a></p>
{% else %}
   <p>{{ form_label(app.session.chanson,"Chanson : ") }}
   {{ form_errors(app.session.chanson) }}
   {{ form_widget(app.session.chanson) }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

You then need to plug the action you want on the `modify` link.

Also note that if your object `chanson` is stored in a session, the right way to access it in your twig template is by using the `app.session` object.

Comment: Ok thank you it's working nice.
My object isn't stored in a session, session is the name of the form I create and render in the view. Just a bad name.